# vim search replace on some specific lines

Tags: regex, vim, replace

Vim substitute command `:%s/old/new/g` will replace all occurrences of `old` by `new`. But I want to do this replacement only in lines that do not start with `#`. I mean in my file there are some lines starting with # (called commented lines) which I want to exclude in search replace. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 11):

You should mix it with the `g` (see `help :global`) command:

```
:%g/^[^#]/s/old/new/
```

Answer (score 5):

```
:v/^#/s/old/new
```

should do the job. check `:h :v` for details.

Comment: Oh, this is the inverse of `g` (as in grep's `-v` flag).

Answer (score 3):

The Answer from Thomas is fine. Another approach would be the negative lookbehind:

`:%s/\(#.*\)\@<!old/new/g`

These method matches every `old` not preceded by a `#` while the method of Thomas matches every line not starting with `#` and then matches every `old` on that line.

The solution of Kent is a little bit more elegant. It uses `:v` which is the same as `:g!`. It matches every line starting with `#` and then runs the command on every **other** line. This has the advantage that the regex gets easier. In your usecase the regex to not match it is quite easy, but often it is way easier to build a regex to match a criteria than one that doesn't match. so the `:v` command helps here.

In your case the `global` (both of the other answers are using `global`) command seems safer, since it only checks for a `#` at the beginning of the line. But depending on the usecase all of the three methods have their advantages